# Cannot boot 17.04 from usb stick

Tags: boot, usb, 17.04

I wanted to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.04.

I created a bootable usb stick in Ubuntu 16.04 using Startup Disk Creator selecting the downloaded 17.04 iso.

I'm using a Kingston 8GB usb stick.

I can select the stick in the BIOS and boot menu, but the system keeps starting up as usual via the main start up disk. Ignoring the usb stick.

I'm reading similar posts about the matter, but I don't find a suitable answer.

Comment: PD. I formatted the stick as ext4 and fat32 just to see if it would make a difference but it doesn't.

Comment: You don't need a USB if you just want to upgrade. Have you tried `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Hi Katu-  I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. At first it seemed to work but then at the end i got an error message. Now, when repeating the commands it tells me everything is up-to-date.

Comment: But i'm just surprised i cannot boot from usb, when i created the bootable usb in Ubuntu..

Comment: `lsb_release -a` will tell you your Ubuntu version. If you need to solve this or other problems, people will be able to help you better with more information in your question. Here they have information to consider before asking https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SDC does not always work one Ubuntu release to the next, try a different installer such as mkusb.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the USB may not actually be formatted or created correctly. You may have to write it to the USB again, using a different burning utility like gnome-disks, because you may see the USB in the BIOS, but that does not necessarily mean it is bootable. I recommend reformatting and burning the USB with the stated tool.

Comment: You mean `gnome-disks`, right?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: I decided to change the OS to CentOS because i want to learn more about the RedHat environment. 

Creating a bootable usb stick was succesful using a command found on this website as follows:

sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync

Comment: PD: i used a 32 GB Sandisk usb stick because the .iso was 8,4 GB.